# Socket.IO 1.0.x: Get socket by id

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In the 0.9.x version, we can get socket by ID like this:

```
io.sockets.socket(socketId)
```

But in 1.0.x we can't. How to find a socket by id in 1.0.x?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For socket.io 1.0 use:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketId]
```

For  0.9 its io.sockets.sockets[socketId] and not io.sockets.socket[socketId]

Comment: For namespaced connections I could not access it via `io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit()` but it did work similarly `var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');` then `nsp.connected[socketId].emit()`. Thanks

Comment: Agreeing with @Luckylooke, I can put it into a one liner like this:
`io.of('/namespace').connected[socketId].emit('message-tag', data, callback)`
I think it is worth to mention that I can also pass a callback function as a bridge to request data from the connected client this way.

Answer (score 23):

**Socket.io Version 4.0.0**

`io.sockets.sockets.get(socketId);`

Comment: This is not working when used with ```cluster adapter```.

Comment: Did you find a solution for cluster/redis adapter?

Comment: None of these answers are working for cluster/redis adapter. It is working fine when we run in a single node. But when it comes to multi nodes with redis adapter, it is not working. Any solution that works for redis adapter?

Answer (score 21):

you can also use like:

```
io.to(socketid).emit();
```

Answer (score 9):

**Version 3.0.3**

```
// in "of", you can put '/' or whatever namespace you're using
    
io.of('/').sockets.get(socketId)
```

Basically, `sockets` is no longer a simple Object.  It's a Map, so you have to use `.get()`.

Comment: Also works for v4.2.0

Answer (score 7):

**Socket.io Version 2.0.3+**

```
    let namespace = null;
    let ns = _io.of(namespace || "/");
    let socket = ns.connected[socketId] // assuming you have  id of the socket
```

Answer (score 3):

The most simlple way I tried is:

```
var socket1 = io.of("/").connected[socketId];
```

Then you can do

```
socket1.join("some room");
socket1.leave("some room");
socket1.emit();
```

or other things you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fetchSockets()` function to fetch the connection using socketId like below.

```
const sockets = await io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets();
```

This solution works perfectly with socket.io redis/adaptor. For more API documentation, refer here https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespacesockets