# Get Socket Object by Id with node, redis-adapter and socket.io

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I'm building a real time webgame with nodejs and socket.io. I'm using  [redis-adapter](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-redis) and [sticky-sessions](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) so i'll able to run a cluster.

My problem is I need to get the socket object of a client using his id. I dont know how i can do it! [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055989/socket-io-1-0-x-get-socket-by-id) there is a socket.io native solution but it works only in non-cluter mode. It's so strange that the redis-adapter is not implementing this functionality!

I could (using [node-redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)) save the entire socket object of every clients in a redis LIST and get it when I need but I don't like this solution. Why do I need to save for each client the entire socket object in redis when I could only save the socket id? Anyway this solution can't work because when I try to save a socket object in redis, i have this error:

```
converting circular structure to JSON
```

so, it seems that sockets has a circluar structure, and they can't be stored in redis as a string (using JSON.stringify(socket) ).

So the point is, as i say: i need the socket object of a specific client using the socket id. I can't store manually all the clients socket object in redis and the redis-adapter for socket io seems is not implementing this functionality. How can i do?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I've run across the same issue. And simply storing the socket inside an HMAP won't work because somewhere in the socket, there will need to be a link to the Websocket and an active HTTP connection

Comment: Now i don't remember perfectly how that story finished!! But maybe i solved with a workaround, storing sockets in memory and using redis also as a message-passing service. So i implemented my own logic to retrieve a socket by his id, searching in every process and comunicating with redis..

Comment: See if this answers your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77122273/11045310