# Socket.io get socket by id not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to access a socket by its id. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055989/socket-io-1-0-x-get-socket-by-id) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041220/sending-message-to-a-specific-id-in-socket-io-1-0?rq=1) stackoverflow posts. However,

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.id]
```

returns undefined.

This also doesn't work :

```
io.to(socket.id).emit("myMessage");
```

Socket is connected to a namespace (socket.id returns /playNS#1HhBtUM-6O_YsRwmAAAF) and socket.io version is 1.4.5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work fine -- I have similar code in a github project and the only thing I do is track socketID and sessionID in an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a socket is connected to a namespace, the first part of socket.id contains that namespace (e.g. `/playNS#1HhBtUM-6O_YsRwmAAAF`) , but `io.sockets.connected` property for that socket would be `/#1HhBtUM-6O_YsRwmAAAF`

In order to properly retrieve the socket I used `io.of('/namespace').connected[socket.id]`.

Similarly, `io.of("/namespace").to(socket.id).emit("myMessage");` to send a message