# Socket.io get socket object by id in cluster mode (Redis- adaptor)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is it possible to get a socket object by  using socketId, if we are running the server in cluster mode or running server in multiple machine (using redis as adaptor).

So suppose in cluster mode, a socket is connected to thread-A, so is it possible to get the socket object when request comes to thread-B.

If not, is there any way by which when I can pass callback function to a socket client using redis-adaptor.

Comment: The actual socket may be in another process so you can't necessarily get the actual socket into your process.  You can use the adapter interface to send messages to any id (the redis adapter will take care of figuring out which process can send to it).  If you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, we could probably help with a solution to that.

Comment: I am using io.to(socketId).emit to emit meesage to a socket id, but I am not able to pass callback function. It is throwing error "callback not supported when broadcasting". Is there anyway to pass callback??

Comment: Please show us your server side code for socket.io, including how you're configuring redis .

Comment: I don't know how to do that with redis.  You could have your client socket send a confirm message back and use that instead of the callback.

Comment: I am facing same problem now. Did you know the solution now? @Jfriend00 Basically to find the status of the socket connection of a user, I am using this code. io.sockets.sockets.get('socket_id') as recommended by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055989/socket-io-1-0-x-get-socket-by-id. But this is not working when I run mulitple nodes with redis adaptor.

Comment: Example: Socket A is connected to Server A and if I execute this code (io.sockets.sockets.get('socket_id')) in Server A it is working. But when I execute the same code in Server B or even in the same server but in different process, it is not working.  As per socket.io documentation it should work when we use any adaptor. Here I'm using redis adaptor. Code: io.adapter(createAdapter(pub, sub)). Please help to solve thi s issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question. Yes, it is possible to get the socket object when request comes to thread-B when you use any adaptor with socket.io, in your case you are already using Redis-adaptor.

```
const sockets = await io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets();
```

fetchSockets() function will return the socket object across nodes. You can follow this API documentation https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespacesockets for more details.