# Get socket object from ID

Tags: socket.io

I am using Socket.io in a nodejs app-

I am storing the socket.id when I receive a connection. However, I need to have the socket object whose id, is the one I stored.
How can I get a Socket object having just the id?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or some demo code so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.IO 1.0.x: Get socket by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055989/socket-io-1-0-x-get-socket-by-id)

Comment: simply use this : io.sockets.connected[socket.id]

Comment: Thanks to both of you:
io.sockets.connected[socket.id] did the trick. It was a dumb question, sorry but I am very new to socket.io